# Identity for adjugate

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations

There is a problem in section 6 of Bill Kahan's document [here](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/MathH110/Cross.pdf), as follows:

Let $\mathbf{R}$ be a $3 \times 3$ real orthogonal matrix with 
$\operatorname{det}(\mathbf{R}) = 1$, and let $\mathbf{v}$ be a unit vector that is an "axis of rotation" for $\mathbf{R}$, in the sense that $\mathbf{R}\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{v}$. Then show that
$$
\operatorname{adj}(\mathbf{R} - \mathbf{I}) = 
\big( 3 - \operatorname{trace}(\mathbf{R}) \big)\mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}^T 
$$ 
He says the problem is "hard".

I suppose I could prove it by brute force just by expanding everything, perhaps using a computer algebra system. But I'd like to find a tidier proof. I'm guessing that there's some trick using eigenvectors and/or the Cayley-Hamilton theorem.

As @hardmath commented, the author says that "$\operatorname{adj}(\mathbf{R} - \mathbf{I})$ must be some nonzero scalar multiple of $\mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}^T\,$". I can't prove that, either. If I could, then what's left is just to show that the multiplier factor is $3 - \operatorname{trace}(\mathbf{R})$.

Comment: In the context of that Section, $\mathbf{v}$ is a particular vector called the "axis" of the orthogonal matrix $\mathbf{R}$.  The author writes "Adj($\mathbf{R– I}$) must be some
nonzero scalar multiple of $\mathbf{vv}^T$".  So the exercise is in a sense just determining which scalar multiple makes it true.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed the question. Your "f" key is somehow producing "d" characters  :-)

Comment: I edited my Comment, but not quickly enough to fool you!  I never remember which $\LaTeX$ command gives the bold font.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably, $R$ is real orthogonal. As it has size 3 and determinant 1, it is a rotation matrix. Therefore, by a change of orthonormal basis (you may use the identity $\operatorname{adj}(P^{-1}AP)=P^{-1}\operatorname{adj}(A)P$), we may assume that
$$
R=\pmatrix{1&0&0\\ 0&\cos t&-\sin t\\ 0&\sin t&\cos t}.
$$
Now you can easily verify the problem statement by calculating $\operatorname{adj}(R-I)$ directly.